# Angular 7 - error using services and pipes

Tags: angular, service, pipe

I have made a npm package with my angular module. Some of it works great. I can use all my components. But if I use a pipe in TS, I get this error

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'workorder/lib/shared/pipes/newline.pipe' in 'C:\development\WorkOrder.Shared.Client.Web\src\app'
```

If I however use the same pipe in my HTML file, it works fine.

I get similar errors when using my services.

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ...

What is wrong ?

Comment: Have you correctly imported pipes and services in your app.module? can you share the code of the module in which you import yours pipes/services? Then if you are wrapping services/pipes in 'shared' modules they must be exported too.

Comment: Could you please show how do you use and provide services? Did you add services from your library to DI?

Comment: Ok I figured out what it is.
When you build an Angular NPM package, you have to expose your services and pipes in a special way.
in my pipes folder, I make a file called index.ts, where I export all my pipes like this
export * from './newline.pipe';

I do the same in my services folder. Make an index.ts file and export my services.

Then I also need to export pipes and services in my "public_api.ts" file.

Now I can use my services and pipes in a separate application using my NPM package

Comment: besides that I of cause also have my services in the provider section in my project.module.ts and my pipes are in my declarations and exports section in the project.module.ts file